# mysql query help to select details of the person with highest id

Tags: mysql, database

how to achieve this without using nested query or sub query.

```
    select * from table_name where id=(select avg(id) from table_name);
```

need some suggestion.

Comment: The average id?  This might return an id in the middle (which might even be deleted).

Answer (score 3):

```
select * from table_name order by id desc limit 1
```

Comment: id is not primary key and it is not indexed.

Comment: That shouldn't matter as long as it's numeric. (Unless your concern is with performance).  Adding an index would help with the sort.

Comment: is there any way with self join. am a little concerned with performance.and it is not unique.

Comment: AFAIK joins will possibly be worse for performance, since it's essentially the same type of operation (getting the max), but doubled.  Typically I'd avoid joining anything on a non-indexed key.  For best performance, you might store a pointer to the last record in table_name, in a separate, smaller table (for example with only one row).

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
SELECT
        *
FROM 
        table_name
ORDER BY 
        id DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: the table is big and am concerned about performance is there any way using self join;

Comment: The query you provided is much faster than JOIN as it eliminates the possibility to match multiple records (specially when id is not unique)

Comment: thanks for help but my boss doesn't allow me to use nested queries .